# How to pass on tracking ID of link and add them to outbound link on page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, hyperlink, tracking

I use tracking IDs for the links that lead to a landing page on my website. For example:

```
mywebsite.com/landingpage1?tid=test1
```

How do I pass on `TID=test1` onto the link that will be the call to action to get to another site?

Tracking Ids can vary depending on where the traffic is coming from.

So I would like the `TID` to be automatically attached to the `TID` of the outbound link on that page.

I am using WordPress on my website. So I presume that any suitable code could be added either at the header of the page or for the entire website.

Comment: Are these links dynamically created? where are you putting the links? Where do the tracking numbers come from? How are the links created?

Comment: Hi @gregbast1994 ,

thank you for your comment.

I create the links myself that lead to my page. I run ads to various audiences. So to identify the origin of the traffic I add tracking IDs to the URL of the link such as:

[link](https://mywebsite.com/?tid=trafficsource1)
[link](https://mywebsite.com/?tid=trafficsource2)
etc...

The inbound link is visible in the browser and also passed on as metadata I guess.

I want the tracking ID to be passed on towards the target website (ClickBank) to identify the origin of the traffic:

[link](outboundlink.com/?tid=trafficsource1)